# Insert usando many to many annotation não funciona

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, annotation

Olá,

Tenho um relacionamento many to many, entre a classe TEAM e NEWS. Estou tentando criar um método para inserir uma "NEWS". Estou utilizando Hibernate com annotation pra mapear as classes.

O insert funciona e persiste corretamente na tabela NEWS, mas na tabela NEWS_TEAM não insere. Não é apresentado nenhum erro...apenas nao insere.

Fiz o teste e adicionei o registro na tabela NEWS_TEAM manualmente, direto no banco, e realizei uma listagem simples usando criteria, e funcionou, porém o insert não funcinoa.

Aguém ja passou por algo parecido?

Segue o metodo insert da classe NewsBusinessImpl:

```
public void create(News news) {
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        session = PoliGenericDAO.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(news);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("create.News.Error: " + e);
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Segue a Entidade NEWS:

```
...

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "newsList", targetEntity = Team.class, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
private Set<Team> teamList;
```

Segue a Entiadade TEAM:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST},  fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "NEWS_TEAM", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "NEWS_ID") })
private Set<News> newsList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os objetos do tipo Team já estejam no banco de dados, você deve adiciona-los na lista do objeto News e só depois disso você poderá adiciona-lo no banco de dados, por exemplo:

```
news.getTeams().addAll(lista de objetos do tipo Team);
session.save(news);
```

Além disso, para cada objeto do tipo Team que esteja na lista do News você também deverá adiciona-lo na lista do Team, o código final seria assim:

```
news.getTeams().addAll(lista de objetos do tipo Team);
news = session.save(news);//Retorna o obj com ID
for(Team objTeam : news.getTeams()){
   objTeam.getNews().add(news);
   session2.save(objTeam);
}
```

Comment: Olá Fábio..obrigado pela resposta...mas o erro não foi o que você falou...eu ja estava fazendo dessa forma...desculpa se n coloquei o código. O erro no meu caso, foi que eu troquei as notações do many to many. A "entidade dominante" na relação estava errada. Vlw a ajuda!!